# Aggregation Multiple arrays

Tags: mongodb, symfony, aggregation-framework

Hey i'm having troubles with getting my aggregation right.

I'm having this dataset and within the collection there are a few million other documents alike:

```
{
  "_id": ObjectId("5757c73344ce54ae1d8b456c"),
  "hostname": "Baklap4",
  "timestamp": NumberLong(1465370500),
  "networkList": [
    {
      "name": "46.243.152.13",
      "openConnections": NumberLong(3)
    },
    {
      "name": "46.243.152.50",
      "openConnections": NumberLong(4)
    }
  ],
  "webserver": "nginx",
  "deviceList": [
    {
      "deviceName": "eth0",
      "receive": NumberLong(183263),
      "transmit": NumberLong(781595)
    },
    {
      "deviceName": "wlan0",
      "receive": NumberLong(0),
      "transmit": NumberLong(0)
    }
  ]
}
```

**What I want:**

I'd like to get a resultset where i'm doing an average (of every numeric value) for every document within a 300 second timespan.

```
[
                [
                    '$match' => [
                        'timestamp' => ['$gte' => $todayMidnight],
                        'hostname' => $serverName
                    ]
                ],
                [
                    '$unwind' => '$networkList'
                ],
                [
                    '$unwind' => '$deviceList'
                ],
                [
                    '$group' => [
                        '_id' => [
                            'interval' => [
                                '$subtract' => [
                                    '$timestamp',
                                    [
                                        '$mod' => ['$timestamp', 300]
                                    ]
                                ]
                            ],
                            'network' => '$networkList.name',
                            'device' => '$deviceList.name',
                        ],
                        'openConnections' => [
                            '$sum' => '$networkList.openConnections'
                        ],
                        'cpuLoad' => [
                            '$avg' => '$cpuLoad'
                        ],
                        'bytesPerSecond' => [
                            '$avg' => '$bytesPerSecond'
                        ],
                        'requestsPerSecond' => [
                            '$avg' => '$requestsPerSecond'
                        ],
                        'webserver' => [
                            '$last' => '$webserver'
                        ],
                        'timestamp' => [
                            '$max' => '$timestamp'
                        ]
                    ]
                ],
                [
                    '$project' => [
                        '_id' => 0,
                        'timestamp' => 1,
                        'cpuLoad' => 1,
                        'bytesPerSecond' => 1,
                        'requestsPerSecond' => 1,
                        'webserver' => 1,
                        'openConnections' => 1,
                        'networkList' => '$networkList',
                        'deviceList' => '$_id.device',
                    ]
                ],
                [
                    '$sort' => [
                        'timestamp' => -1
                    ]
                ]
            ];
```

Yet this doesn't give me a list with all devices and per device an average of received and trasmited bytes.

How would one get those?

Comment: are you pulling the data from database ? if yes, can you submit the whole structure of the data  ? - it's best to do the aggregation in database with query

Comment: will 10 minutes interval work for you?

Comment: @Miro Yes i'm pulling the data from MongoDB. And the datastructure is like the first dataset.

Comment: @profesor79 this will work too, I only have to change the 300 seconds (5 minutes) to 600 second.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

per given example I was able to get result using this mongo shel query:

```
var projectTime = {
    $project : {
        _id : 1,
        hostname : 1,
        timestamp : 1,
        networkList : 1,
        webserver : 1,
        deviceList : 1,
        isoDate : {
            $add : [new Date(0), {
                    $multiply : ["$timestamp", 1000]
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
var group = {
    $group : {

        "_id" : {
            time : {
                "$add" : [{
                        "$subtract" : [{
                                "$subtract" : ["$isoDate", new Date(0)]
                            }, {
                                "$mod" : [{
                                        "$subtract" : ["$isoDate", new Date(0)]
                                    },
                                    1000 * 60 * 5 // 1000 milsseconds * 60 seconds * 5 minutes
                                ]
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    new Date(0)
                ]
            },
            "hostname" : "$hostname",
            "deviceList_deviceName" : "$deviceList.deviceName",
            "networkList_name" : "$networkList.name",
        },

        xreceive : {
            $sum : "$deviceList.receive"
        },
        xtransmit : {
            $sum : "$deviceList.transmit"
        },
        xopenConnections : {
            $avg : "$networkList.openConnections"
        },

    }
}

var unwindNetworkList = {
    $unwind : "$networkList"
}
var unwindSeviceList = {
    $unwind : "$deviceList"
}

var match = {
    $match : {
        "_id.time" : ISODate("2016-06-09T08:05:00.000Z")
    }
}

var finalProject = {
    $project : {
        _id : 0,
        timestamp : "$_id.time",
        hostname : "$_id.hostname",
        deviceList_deviceName : "$_id.deviceList_deviceName",
        networkList_name : "$_id.networkList_name",
        xreceive : 1,
        xtransmit : 1,
        xopenConnections : 1
    }
}
db.baklap.aggregate([projectTime, unwindNetworkList,
        unwindSeviceList,

        group,
        match,
        finalProject
    ])
db.baklap.findOne()
```

then output:

```
{
    "xreceive" : NumberLong(0),
    "xtransmit" : NumberLong(0),
    "xopenConnections" : 4.0,
    "timestamp" : ISODate("2016-06-09T08:05:00.000Z"),
    "hostname" : "Baklap4",
    "deviceList_deviceName" : "wlan0",
    "networkList_name" : "46.243.152.50"
}
{
    "xreceive" : NumberLong(183263),
    "xtransmit" : NumberLong(781595),
    "xopenConnections" : 4.0,
    "timestamp" : ISODate("2016-06-09T08:05:00.000Z"),
    "hostname" : "Baklap4",
    "deviceList_deviceName" : "eth0",
    "networkList_name" : "46.243.152.50"
}
{
    "xreceive" : NumberLong(183263),
    "xtransmit" : NumberLong(781595),
    "xopenConnections" : 3.0,
    "timestamp" : ISODate("2016-06-09T08:05:00.000Z"),
    "hostname" : "Baklap4",
    "deviceList_deviceName" : "eth0",
    "networkList_name" : "46.243.152.13"
}
{
    "xreceive" : NumberLong(0),
    "xtransmit" : NumberLong(0),
    "xopenConnections" : 3.0,
    "timestamp" : ISODate("2016-06-09T08:05:00.000Z"),
    "hostname" : "Baklap4",
    "deviceList_deviceName" : "wlan0",
    "networkList_name" : "46.243.152.13"
}
```

The main point is be aware than every time `$unwind` is processed, our data gets a bit of pollution. This could give a side effect when summing data **(average will be same as (2+2+3+3)/4 is same as (2+3)/2))**

To check that - you could add `x:{$push:"$$ROOT"}` in group stage and check values after pipeline executed - as you will have all source documents for given data peroid

Comment: In both cases the openConnections should be summed up and an average over receive and transmit. So if i'm correct that'll change xOpenConnections in the output to 7. Apart from that well done! Anyway to change the format of timestamp to `31 - 12 23:59` format?

Comment: Could you tell more about time format.  Didn't get that

Comment: The format as i thought was clear will be `Days - MonthNumber hours:minutes` with all double digets so `1` would become `01` yet `11` would stay `11`

Comment: @Baklap4 use [this $dateToString](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dateToString/) :-)